# How to use sysenter for 64 bits userland programs linked against SystemⅤ libraries?

Tags: linux, security, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

Is it possible to use sysenter in a 64 bits program on Linux ? Or is it impossible to adapt the use of `sysenter` with the SystemⅤ calling convention without getting other dynamic link libraries crashing *(I know the 32 bits way won’t work but I just want to know if it’s possible to work around this like with`int 0x80`)* ?

There is very few documentation around using sysenter in 32 bits, so I couldn’t found anything for 64 bits.
I know this not recommended but it’s the only opcode I can use to trigger a system call as part of bug bounty hunting exploit where the program need to exit using a special function that can be trigger only from normal execution.

Comment: What do you mean "not in the manual"?  Intel's insn set ref (html extract here: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSENTER.html) says it's valid in long mode and compat/legacy modes.  I assume you could use it to access the 32-bit ABI from a 64-bit process, but I didn't check that the complex dance between kernel and user-space to correctly save / restore RIP, RFLAGS, the stack pointer, and whatever else (I forget) works correctly for 64-bit.  You could check by looking at the kernel's sysret return implementation, to see if it might truncate something to 32b.

Comment: If you call the C library function that corresponds to the system call you're trying to use you don't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: I'm sure you *could* design a viable 64-bit ABI around SYSENTER/SYSEXIT (otherwise Intel wouldn't have made it valid in long mode), so the only question is what happens in Linux's SYSENTER entry point and/or SYSEXIT return path.

Comment: @RossRidge : I don’t want to call a C library function, I want to perform a 64 bits system call manually in assembly in a regular 64 bits Linux program.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I was talking about the official manual. I don’t want to design a new ᴀʙɪ and recompile all libraries. I just want to perform a malloc request in assembly with sysenter. Even if I know I could call glibc.

Comment: There is no malloc system call. Obviously you want to do this "manually" but given all the problems you're having (not understanding the manual, not understanding how Linux system calls work, not knowing what is and isn't a system call) my suggestion is that you should reconsider whether this is what you really want. In reality there's only one good reason for "manually" invoking Linux system calls and that's because you're writing your own C runtime library to replace glibc.

Comment: @RossRidge : yes, I was meaning `srbk`. `here's only one good reason for "manually" invoking Linux system calls and that's because you're writing your own C runtime library to replace glibc.` Or because I found a stack overflow issue but maintainers refuse to fix to fix arguing that it can’t be used to open a shell, even if I proved the control of a function pointer. The only instructions that can be used to perform a system call are `sysret`*(0x0F07)* & `sysenter`*(0x0F34)*. Other places with code are temporarily execution protected. And yes,I never wrote code to perform a system call before.

Comment: So my question is similar to [this one](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/how-to-use-sysenter-under-linux) but for 64 bits. I just need to find if the sysenter instruction can be used on 64 bits Intel and how I can perform a system call with it for the SystemⅤ calling convention .

Comment: You can't, as you can see from the question you linked SYSENTER isn't remotely compatible with the AMD64 System V calling convention. Assuming what you're doing isn't illegal, and you aren't trying to exploit a buffer overflow on someone else's system without their **explicit** permission, you should probably edit your post to include the full details of what your real problem is.

Comment: @RossRidge :`isn't remotely compatible with the AMD64 System V calling convention.` Wrong ! this isn’t not enough to say that’s not possible. The calling convention says that`syscall`is the instruction that need to be used. But this doesn’t prevent using `int 0x80`Though differently from 32 bits and with`syscall`. My question is about doing the same for sysenter. Because basically, it doesn’t require kernel side support *(which isn’t the case for`sysret`)*. I have the permission of doing it *(bug bounty)* and I have [a background in security research](https://bounty.github.com).

Comment: @RossRidge : they want the proof a shell can be opened on Linux otherwise they’ll correct nothing since the crash can’t be triggered by using the service normally. It’s up to you to decide whether leaving an exploitable threat or not.

Comment: Uhuh. Well, I guess there's nothing more for me to say then. Since you're the expert on these matters you should be more than capable of answering your question yourself. When you do figure it out, please don't forget to post it as answer here.

Comment: `I was talking about the official manual`.  http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SYSENTER.html *is* extracted directly from Intel's official IA-32 / IA-32e manual, Volume 2, the instruction set reference.  If you want to look at the official PDF, see the link to Intel's manuals in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), but it says the same thing: SYSENTER is a legal instruction in long mode and compat mode.  I expect that if anything you can only get access to the 32-bit ABI with it (even from a 64-bit process).  This is the same as `int 0x80`: 32-bit ABI even from 64-bit code

Comment: You can take out the "disabled at hardware level" speculation.  I keep linking you Intel's official documentation for what happens when SYSENTER executes, which documents the operation in compat mode and in long mode.  Please narrow down your question to only the parts that aren't obviously ruled out by the documentation.  e.g. what actually happens on Linux.

Comment: @PeterCordes : So you left my biggest concern. Question scope is know narrowed to the Linux case.

Comment: I never claimed to know the answer to what happens if you run it in Linux.  But before anyone can give a useful answer, your question needed to be edited to actually ask a real question that wasn't trivially answered by the official docs.

Comment: @PeterCordes : My question is unrelated to the sysret bug. All I want is to perform a jump to a 16 bytes aligned address that contains the sysenter instruction. Initially, I thought I wouldn’t be able to perform the instruction at the hardware level. After writing the question I realized http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2894/17379 is 32 bits only.

Comment: If Linux's sysenter entry point treats 64-bit processes the same as 32-bit processes, then yeah it probably isn't usable.  If the kernel maps the 32-bit VDSO page into 64-bit processes (which it probably doesn't), you could maybe even jump to that same code and have it run as 64-bit machine code.  (The push/pop instructions would be 64-bit push/pop instructions, but the `mov %esp, %ebp` would still be a 32-bit mov, truncating the stack pointer.  It might work in a process using the x32 ABI, or which had the stack in the low 4GiB for some other reason.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : yeah, I think it would call the 32 bits wrapper. However, is it possible to mange to save the register at some place and parameter the stack so the process doesn’t crash when sysexit write the return value ?

Comment: How much custom code can you inject?  Can you write your own code that uses SYSENTER, or is jumping to the VDSO your own option?  I don't think the SYSENTER VDSO is even mapped in a 64-bit process, but I might be wrong.  If it is, two 64-bit pushes equal four 32-bit pushes, so you might have to pack two things into upper/lower halves of a single register.  Also you (or someone else that wants to answer this question) would have to check which registers get truncated to 32-bit (or worse, left with high garbage).  That might include RSP, but maybe not.  Maybe just a 32-bit pointer in EBP works.

Comment: @PeterCordes : I can only load validated native client code by calling nacl_dyncode_create from the overflow *([the trampoline has a fixed address](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/nacl-glibc/+/master/sysdeps/nacl/nacl_syscalls.h "see NACL_SYSCALL_ADDR"))*. However, their seems to be bug in the validator : I found a sysenter instruction at an aligned memory address. So in theory, I can jump to it. But as this is native client : the reachable memory address space is 2³²+r15. However, while I can’t write to r15, I read the register value which is set at random because of ᴀꜱʟʀ.

Comment: Sounds like you should read Linux's SYSENTER entry-point code, to see how it decides where to return to.

Comment: @PeterCordes : Explaining how in an answer would be nice. Also, does sysret can have a purpose from userland ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use them, but they use the 32-bit entry point of the kernel (check the code for more).

The actual location (and code) of this entry point depends on you kernel version.
For versions 4.2 and newer it is [entry_SYSENTER_32](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/entry/entry_32.S?v=4.2#L300).
For versions 4.1 and older it is [ia32_sysenter_target](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/ia32/ia32entry.S?v=4.1#L110).

Finally, SYSRET is not available at userspace (it can only be executed from ring 0). Check the Intel manual description of the instruction.

Comment: You can use the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI from 64-bit processes (with 32-bit pointers, of course).  Are you saying that that's the case for SYSENTER as well?  It looks like no, since `pushq_cfi    $__USER32_CS` for `pt_regs->cs` means the return to user-space will happen in 32-bit mode, right?